# which ide must be used for javascript development?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ide

What is the best ide for developing html5/js project ?It must have powerful content assist 
and it must  manage js/css / html files easily.Is there anyone suggest eclipse or visual studio ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919977/ide-for-node-js-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

I suggest Eclipse, it is:

- Simple
- Free
- Ability to deploy client side content on web application.
- It offers:

  - CSS editor
  - JS editor
  - HTML editor
- Can be easily integrated to most web servers

Answer (score 1):

Try WebStorm by JetBrains. It even can handle preprocessing for sass/less/coffie

Answer (score 1):

If you want a full IDE i recomend [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) or [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) by JetBrains. Both do the same with javascript but PHPStorm includes PHP suport. Both have autocomplete, and full support for the main JS libraries and tools. Also have support for CSS precompilers and for languages compiling to JS (for example typescript). You can run UnitTests inside the IDE from multiple origins (mocha, js-test-driver, jasmine, Karma ...).

If you want a lighter tool the i would recomend [Sublime-text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It's not an IDE, but is really powerful. It has plenty of addons to improve this tool.

I recomend you to visit their webs and compare.

I wouldn't recomend eclipse nor visual studio, but if I had to choose I would take eclipse.

Comment: Does sublime-text 2 provide autocomplete as referencing current document , third part libs and native js functions ? And why don't you choose eclipse or v. studio ?

Comment: The sublime-text autocompletes any thing that has been written in the current document. If you need more you can search on its addons and packages and that improves this. I don't choose any of those because I consider JetBrains tools better and more complete. The only dowside of this tool is that's a paid IDE. Both Jetbrains tools and sublime-text have a 30 day trial.